# Remote Samba share not accessible

Tags: networking, network-shares, samba

I want to connect to a samba share i set up on a vps with a static ip.
The ports are open and the samba service is listening on them, but still if i want to connect to that share it does not work at all by remote.
On the server it self i can use the samba client.
The windows error is translated from german to english: the network authentication failed

Here the path i am using while connecting(notice i replaced the ip with an example):

```
\\123.123.321.321\public
```

Here the config part:

```
[public]
path = /home/sambauser 
public = yes
writable = yes
read only = no
comment = smb share
printable = no
guest ok = yes
available = yes
browseable = yes
```

The Global settings:

```
[global]
workgroup = smb
security = user
map to guest = Bad Password
```

Regards
Yann HN

Comment: SMB/SAMBA is not an Internet-worthy protocol, and you should not attempt to expose it to the public Internet. Use a Web-safe protocol like SFTP, or at least tunnel access to your SAMBA service via SSH or VPN.

Comment: That is not used in production, its just a test.
I know Samba(1 and 2) is not safe.
Please do not post such useless comments.
I cannot use a tunnel